# Alfresco's SOLR using the wrong drive?

Tags: solr, alfresco

I just did a migration of Alfresco to a new server with a different drive layout.  Instead of being on "C", it's now on "E".  I changed the alfresco-global.properties references to point to E.  However, SOLR still insists on writing it's index files to drive C. It appears that SOLR should use dir.root (which points to E), however, it's not (at least for the index files...  All the rest of SOLR is on drive E and it's functioning).

How can I get SOLR to use the new drive, instead of C, for the index files?

Comment: Did you move the SOLR war, data directory, tomcat etc?

Comment: Yes.  Whole thing moved over.  On initial startup, search wouldn't work at all.  I forced a rebuild, still didn't work.  I did the directory clearing procedure and then it rebuilt, but in the incorrect location.

Comment: IIRC there's a special context file you drop into the Tomcat that SOLR runs in, which tells it where to find the war etc, did you try updating that?

Comment: Nope, was unaware of such a thing.  I'll go do some research in that area!

Comment: The [Alfresco install guide for SOLR](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/solr-install-config.html) should provide some hints!

Comment: @Gagravarr make that an answer so I can add my notes/comments and accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alfresco provide an [Installation guide for Solr](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/solr-install-config.html) which covers most of what you'll need.

From there, you'll see that in the `context.xml` file you copy into the Tomcat directory you can set the `docBase` to control where it finds the war, and `solr/home` for where it finds most of the rest of the Alfresco Solr setup. Finally, in the Solr home, there's a per-core `solrcore.properties` file, in which you can set where the index files get placed.

Comment: The critical part was setting data.dir.root in each of: <SOLR-ARCHIVE>/archive-SpacesStore/conf/solrcore.properties &
<SOLR-ARCHIVE>/workspace-SpacesStore/conf/solrcore.properties  Then I copied the data over and rebooted!